# contour integral involving the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, gamma-function

Function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, defined as

$$f(z) = x^{-z} (\sin(\pi z))^{-2} \left [ \left (-\frac{z}{2} \right )! \right ]^{-4} \left [\left (\frac{z}{2} - \frac12 \right)! \right ]^{-2}$$

where $x$ is a positive constant, $z\in \mathbb{C}$, and where $z!$ is the $\Gamma(z+1)$,

has double-poles at $z = -1, -3, -5 \ldots$ and at $z = 2, 4, 6 \ldots$

Can you please help me compute the residues of those poles?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I fixed up the problem statement as far as I could understand the OP's intentions.  Perhaps the OP could verify that I faithfully captured what (s)he is trying to ask.